# How to make a Two-way Converter in Kotlin? (Working in java)

Tags: android, kotlin, converters, android-databinding

I am getting this error:

> Error:(32, 50) cannot find method indexFromModel(android.databinding.ObservableList<br.com.martinlabs.usecase.model.GrupoDoPrincipal>, br.com.martinlabs.usecase.model.GrupoDoPrincipal) in class br.com.martinlabs.usecase.viewtools.Converters

But I have this methods on `Converters`: (I have tried with a class with companion object inside it too)

```
object Converters {

    fun indexFromModel(list: ObservableList<GrupoDoPrincipal>, model: GrupoDoPrincipal): Int {
        return list.indexOfFirst { it?.id == model?.id }
    }

    @InverseMethod("indexFromModel")
    fun indexToModel(list: ObservableList<GrupoDoPrincipal>, index: Int): GrupoDoPrincipal {
        return index.let { list[it] }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
<Spinner
    android:selectedItemPosition="@={Converters.indexFromModel(vm.allGrupoDoPrincipal, vm.principal.grupoDoPrincipal)}"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

---

This methods works on Java:

```
public static int indexFromModel(ObservableList<GrupoDoPrincipal> list, GrupoDoPrincipal model) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).getId() == model.getId()) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

@InverseMethod("indexFromModel")
public static GrupoDoPrincipal indexToModel(ObservableList<GrupoDoPrincipal> list, int index) {
    return list.get(index);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kotlin `object` methods not truly `static`. For make it static you need to add annotation `@JvmStatic` for this methods:

```
object Converters {

    @JvmStatic
    fun indexFromModel(list: ObservableList<GrupoDoPrincipal>, model: GrupoDoPrincipal): Int {
        return list.indexOfFirst { it?.id == model?.id }
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @InverseMethod("indexFromModel")
    fun indexToModel(list: ObservableList<GrupoDoPrincipal>, index: Int): GrupoDoPrincipal {
        return index.let { list[it] }
    }
}
```